Issue related to speech to text in flutter
I'm working with speech to text in flutter, When I open the application first time it is working fine but when I navigate to next screen and then come back to previous screen speech to text is recognizing words but not showing in TextFormField.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

class AppFunc {
  static final AppFunc _appFunc = AppFunc._internal();

  factory AppFunc() {
    return _appFunc;
  }

  AppFunc._internal();
  stt.SpeechToText? speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  bool isListening = false;
  String text = '';

  void listen(TextEditingController? questionController,
      Function(Function() fn) state) async {
    print('text is $text');
    print('text in the controller ${questionController?.text}');

    if (!isListening) {
      bool available = await speech!.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) {
          print('onStatus : on voctest val is $val');
          if (val == 'notListening') {
            text = '';
          }

          if (val == 'done') {
            if (questionController?.text.isEmpty ?? true) {
              print('isDone::');

              print('isDone::1');
              print(
                  'this is text return by captilized ${capitalizeFirstLetter(text)}');
              questionController?.text = capitalizeFirstLetter(text);

              // update();

              //  setState(() {});
            } else {
              print('in else of done${text}');
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                if (text.isNotEmpty) {
                  print(
                      'this is print where if condition inside text is not empty ${capitalizeFirstLetter(text)}');
                  questionController?.text +=
                      ' . ${capitalizeFirstLetter(text)}';
                  // update();

                  // setState(() {});
                }
              });
            }

            //   text = '';
            isListening = false;
            state(() {});
          }
        },
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      print('available at start is $available');

      if (available) {
        print('available at end is $available');
        isListening = true;
        state(() {});
        // setState(() => isListening = true);
        speech!.listen(onResult: (val) {
          print('enter');

          print('reconize word is ${val.recognizedWords}');
          text = val.recognizedWords;
          print('this is conteollet value${questionController?.text.isEmpty}');
          // update();
          state(() {});
        });
      }
    } else {
      isListening = false;
      // setState(() => );
      // speech?.cancel();
      speech!.stop();
      state(() {});
    }
  }

  fun(Function(Function() fn) state) async {
    await speech?.cancel();
    print('function called');
    text = '';
    // state(() {});
    print('this is the data ${speech?.isListening}');
  }

  String capitalizeFirstLetter(String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty) return word;
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  }
}

Here is my UI code.
import 'package:avatar_glow/avatar_glow.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speek/functions.dart';
import 'package:speek/screen2.dart';

class ScreenFirst extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenFirst({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScreenFirst> createState() => _ScreenFirstState();
}

class _ScreenFirstState extends State<ScreenFirst> {
  var questionController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    print('this is init state of screen 1');
    questionController = TextEditingController();
    print('this is the question controller value${questionController.text}');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    AppFunc().fun(setState);
    questionController.text = '';
    questionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
            controller: questionController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            // inputFormatters: [_textFormatter],
            maxLines: null,
            // focusNode: focusNode,
            // onTap: () => chatBotController.questionConroller?.selection =
            //     TextSelection(
            //         baseOffset: 0,
            //         extentOffset:
            //             chatBotController.questionConroller?.text.length ?? 0),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                // fillColor: Colors.yellow, // Highlight color
                // filled: true,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                hintText: 'Say Something....',
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.grey),
                prefixIcon: AvatarGlow(
                  animate: AppFunc().isListening,
                  glowColor: AppFunc().isListening
                      ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                      : Colors.white,
                  //   endRadius: 75.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  //  repeatPauseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  repeat: true,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      // await audioPlayer.stop();
                      // await stopSpeak();
                      AppFunc().listen(questionController, setState);
                      // AppUtils.listen(
                      //     questionConroller?.value,
                      //     setState);
                      // setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                        AppFunc().isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none),
                  ),
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                AppFunc obj1 = AppFunc();
                AppFunc obj2 = AppFunc();
                print(obj1 == obj2);

                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenSecond()));
              },
              child: Text('Tap'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

